# group multiple plot in one figure python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

My function return 28 plots ( figure) but i need to group them on one figure   this is my code for generating 28 plots

```
for cat in df.ASS_ASSIGNMENT.unique() :
    a = df.loc[df['ASS_ASSIGNMENT'] == cat]
    dates = a['DATE']
    prediction = a['CSPL_RECEIVED_CALLS']
    plt.plot(dates,prediction)  
    plt.ylabel("nmb_app")
    plt.legend([cat.decode('utf-8')],loc='best')
    plt.xlabel(cat.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Do you want basically 28 lines on the same plot or 28 separate entire plots? Do they share axes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `plt.subplots`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=7, nrows=4)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    x = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 20)
    y = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 20)
    ax.scatter(x, y)
    ax.set_title('Axis {}'.format(i))

plt.tight_layout()
```

---

Going a little deeper, as Mauve points out, it depends if you want 28 curves in a single plot in a single figure or 28 individual plots each with its own axis all in one figure.

Assuming you have a dataframe, `df`, with 28 columns you can put all 28 curves on a single plot in a single figure using `plt.subplots` like so,

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
df.plot(color=colors, ax=ax1)
plt.legend(ncol=4, loc='best')
```

[image]

If instead you want 28 individual axes all in one figure you can use `plt.subplots` this way

```
fig2, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=7)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    df[df.columns[i]].plot(color=colors[i], ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(df.columns[i])
```

[image]

---

Here `df` looks like

```
In [114]: df.shape
Out[114]: (15, 28)

In [115]: df.head()
Out[115]: 
         IYU        ZMK        DRO       UIC       DOF       ASG       DLU  \
0   0.970467   1.026171  -0.141261  1.719777  2.344803  2.956578  2.433358   
1   7.982833   7.667973   7.907016  7.897172  6.659990  5.623201  6.818639   
2   4.608682   4.494827   6.078604  5.634331  4.553364  5.418964  6.079736   
3   1.299400   3.235654   3.317892  2.689927  2.575684  4.844506  4.368858   
4  10.690242  10.375313  10.062212  9.150162  9.620630  9.164129  8.661847   

         BO1       JFN       S9Q    ...          X4K       ZQG       2TS  \
0   2.798409  2.425745  3.563515    ...     7.623710  7.678988  7.044471   
1   8.391905  7.242406  8.960973    ...     5.389336  5.083990  5.857414   
2   7.631030  7.822071  5.657916    ...     2.884925  2.570883  2.550461   
3   6.061272  4.224779  5.709211    ...     4.961713  5.803743  6.008319   
4  10.240355  9.792029  8.438934    ...     6.451223  5.072552  6.894701   

        RS0       P6T       FOU       LN9       CFG       C9D       ZG2  
0  9.380106  9.654287  8.065816  7.029103  7.701655  6.811254  7.315282  
1  3.931037  3.206575  3.728755  2.972959  4.436053  4.906322  4.796217  
2  3.784638  2.445668  1.423225  1.506143  0.786983 -0.666565  1.120315  
3  5.749563  7.084335  7.992780  6.998563  7.253861  8.845475  9.592453  
4  4.581062  5.807435  5.544668  5.249163  6.555792  8.299669  8.036408
```

and was created by

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import random

m = 28
n = 15

def random_data(m, n):
    return np.cumsum(np.random.randn(m*n)).reshape(m, n)

def id_generator(number, size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    sequence = []
    for n in range(number):
        sequence.append(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))
    return sequence

df = pd.DataFrame(random_data(n, m), columns=id_generator(number=m, size=3))
```

Colors was defined as

```
import seaborn as sns
colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(28, rot=-0.4)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what isn't working? Are you trying to do something like the top figure or bottom figure? Adding a sample of your data would be helpful.

Comment: what if there are 27 rather than 28 subplots that one intended to plot? Also what if one wants to draw multi plots of one column base on the value another column rather than plot multiple columns?

Comment: @JasonGoal as for your first question, you could either reshape the subplots to 9x3 or live with having an empty subplot. As for your second question, I recommend opening a new question that better clarifies what you want to do.