# Scatter plot and normal plot on same figure in Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Jupyter I want to first plot via `plt.scatter` and then via `plt.plot`
but I want to show both on the same plot/figure.

I.e. I want the curve from `plt.plot` to appear visually
on the same plot as the scatter plot.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: Please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492681/group-multiple-plot-in-one-figure-python

Comment: @Ahmadhassan No, my problem seems to be specific for Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very small example:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 5))
ax.plot(x, y1)
ax.plot(x, y2)
```

You can replace one of the plots with a scatter plot, add others, ..
In this case, ax is an axes instance however, if you specify other parameters for subplots, e.g. plt.subplots(2, 1), ax will be an iterable (numpy array) of axes instances. Thus you will need to access the ax on which you want to plot:

```
ax[1].plot() or if 2d ax[1, 1].plot()
```

Finally, the method `ax.plot()` takes basically the same argument than `plt.plot()`. However the syntax to set the `title`, the `xlim`, the `ylim`, the `xlabel`, the `ylabel`, is slightly different.

Example in jupyter:

[image]

Comment: The result/drawing from the 2nd plot doesn't appear visually in Jupyter.

Comment: Tried it already before posting ;) No luck

Comment: @peter.petrov And I believe jupyter needs a line at the top of the file in an executable cell: %matplotlib inline : c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline

Comment: I see the visual result but only from the 1st (scatter) plot. The second call just writes: `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1fbd994aac8>]` but shows no graphical output.

Comment: @peter.petrov You made me install jupyter to test it.. Works fine.

Comment: Oh, you're doing it in a single cell, I am doing it in 2 cells (the 2 calls, I mean).

Comment: if you want to update a plot with successive calls you need to tell jupyter to load an interactive backend: `%matplotlib ipympl` or `%matplotlib notebook`. If you use `%matplotlib inline`, the png image produced after the first call will not be updated automatically.

Comment: @peter.petrov if you are running inline then you can't run the second cell. I am inferring that you are creating the figure + axes in 1 cell, and atleast are plotting the second line in a different cell. That does not work as %matplotlib inline produces a png, although the artist is added to the axis the png is not dynamic. You can verify this by using the `%matplotlib notebook` (jupyter notbook) or `%matplotlib widget` (Jupyterlab) backends. Put the plotting in the same cell and it would work.